# Find the radius of convergence of the power series representation of $\frac{tan(\frac{z}{2})}{(z+2)(z+3)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

We are given the following function:
$$\frac{tan(\frac{z}{2})}{(z+2)(z+3)}$$
How do we find the radius of convergence for the power series, representing that function around $z = 0$?

The power series representation for $tan(\frac{z}{2})$ is:
$$\frac{z}{2} + \frac{z^3}{24} + \frac{z^5}{240} + O(z^7)$$
The power series representation for $\frac{1}{(z+2)(z+3)}$ is:
$$\frac{1}{6} - \frac{5z}{36} + \frac{19z^2}{216} + O(z^3)$$

Then I multiply both to obtain:
$$\frac{z}{12} - \frac{5z^2}{72} + \frac{11z^3}{216} - \frac{5z^4}{162} + \frac{697z^5}{38800} + O(z^6)$$

I don't know how to find the radius of convergence from that. Is there a way to convert it to a representation of summation and the n<sup>th</sup> term in the power series, so that for example, we can use the ratio test to find the radius or is there another way to find it?

Comment: Finding the series is unnecessary. The radius of convergence is the distance to the nearest pole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest singularities of the function are located at $z=-2,-3,\pm\pi$. The closest one to $0$ is $-2$, thus the radius of convergence of the series centered at $0$ would be $2$.

Comment: Is that a theorem or is it the general definition of the radius of convergence? Because the definition I have doesn't say that

Comment: @Ivalin it is a consequence of the analyticity of holomorphic functions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886731/proof-that-radius-of-convergence-extend-to-nearest-singularity

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks!