Derivative of function with values in a topological vector space
Let $E$ be a Hausdorff topological vector space and $f:\mathbb{R} \to E$ a function.
Let us call $f$ differentiable at $x$ if
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$
exists (as a limit in $E$).
If this limit exists, then
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e'(f(x+h))-e'(f(x))}{h}
$$
exists for any $e' \in E'$, i.e. $e' \circ f$ is differentiable at $x$ in the usual sense.
Is the reverse true? Under which conditions?
My guess would be that if $E'$ separates points and $E$ is complete (or maybe only sequentially complete), then the existence of all these "scalar derivatives" would imply the existence of the derivative as $E$-valued function, but I'm not able to show this or find a reference.

I guess Theorem 1.1 of https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2016-17/holomorphic_vector-valued.pdf might be useful for you.

That does indeed seem like what I want! On first inspection, though, the proof seems a bit odd/incomplete and seemingly needs the weak regularity to be 2 degrees higher. I'll look at it a bit more carefully, since his notes are usually very clear.

It is a bit annoying that this notion is called weakly differentiable as one mostly gets results about Sobolev spaces on google. I do not know whether weak differentiability implies strong differentiability. So far I have only used that weakly holomorphic implies holomorphic in Hilbert spaces. I have never worked with topological vectors spaces.

This https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255039/for-a-banach-space-e-is-it-sufficient-to-check-differentiability-of-f-u-to seems to answer your question in the negative (even for Hilbert spaces).

This seems to settle it: weak $C^k$ does not imply strong $C^k$, but does imply strong $C^{k-1}$, if $E$ is quasi-complete.

To summarize:
No: being weakly $C^k$ does not imply being strongly $C^k$
Yes: being weakly $C^{k+1}$ does imply being strongly $C^k$, if $E$ is Hausdorff and quasi-complete. A full proof can be found in Schwartz, L. Espaces de fonctions différentiables a valeurs vectorielles. J. Anal. Math. 4, 88–148 (1954), particularly Lemme II on page 146.
