# power series representation of function on the whole disc

Tags: complex-analysis

if we adopte the following definition for a analytic function :

$\textbf{Definition }$

$\bullet$ A function $f$ is called analytic at a point $z_{0} \in \mathbb{C}$ if there exist $r>0$ and a sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ such that
$\forall z\in D(z_0,r) : f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}\left(z-z_{0}\right)^{n}$.

$\bullet$ A function is called analytic in an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ if it is analytic at each point of $U$.

$\textbf{My question is : }$

if $f$ is analytic on $D(0,R)$

can we find a  sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ such that
$\forall z\in D(0,R) : f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n}$?

$\textbf{My try is : }$

Yes we can, because  there is a $r>0$ and a sequence  sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ such that $\forall z\in D(0,r) : f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n}$.

Then if $r<R$, we can have by Abel lemma another $r'>r$ such that
$\forall z\in D(0,r') : f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n}$.

And so on.

What what I want is rigorous proof.

Comment: The answer is yes. This is just a rephrasing of the result talked about here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886731/proof-that-radius-of-convergence-extend-to-nearest-singularity

Comment: thanks..but many books have in proofs of Caushy formula this fact so i try to find another way maybe elemantary way to proof it.